# Sending a 3D model from Fusion 360 to Ultimaker Cura for printing fails

Tags: ultimaker-cura, fusion360

How do I 3D print to Ultimaker Cura from Fusion 360?
(from: File > 3D Print)

I added Cura to the 3D print list, but whenever I click OK, the application does not open.

Comment: Works just fine for SuperSlicer / PrusaSlicer. Fusion 360 simply creates an .stl and opens your specified slicer with it - similar to dragging the file over a link to the application.
Must be a Cura problem.

Comment: If you use the "Custom" option, you can set that to Cura.exe from the correct directory and use that.